# Updating all files with typemap edits in Perforce

Tags: version-control, perforce

I've set up my own perforce server recently and uploaded my project to it, then I realized I made a mistake in the typemap, but the only way to change the type in the existing files that I know of is to use `p4 reopen` and `p4 edit` and specify the type which feels hard to do globally (I have a UE4 project on a custom engine build so a lot of files are involved).

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I think I found a way, `p4 edit -t auto ...`. Will let you all know if it works!

Comment: Yup, that's the way!  (This is the exact use case `auto` is for!)